# Rails - running threads after method has exited

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, exception

When the client changes his profile picture it hits the `update` method, which responds with `update.js.erb`. This is a fast and straightforward process. However, behind the scenes on the server, a bunch of files (10 of them) is generated from the profile picture and these need to be uploaded to an Amazon bucket from the server. This a lengthy process and I don't want to make the client wait until it is finished. Moreover, the file uploads often fail with a `RequestTimeoutException` because they take longer than 15 seconds.

All this raises many questions:

How do you do the 10 file generation/upload after the `update` method has exited? Threads are killed after the main method has finished.

How do you catch an exception inside a thread? The following code does not catch the timeout exceptions.

```
threads = []

threads << Thread.new {
  begin
    # upload file 1 ....
  rescue Rack::Timeout::RequestTimeoutException => e
    # try to upload again ....
  else
  ensure
  end
}

threads << Thread.new {
  begin
    # upload file 2 ....
  rescue Rack::Timeout::RequestTimeoutException => e
    # try to upload again ....
  else
  ensure
  end
}

threads.each { |thr|
  thr.join
}
```

What's the best way to try to upload a file again if it timed out?

What is the best solution to this problem?

Comment: why not use a well supported background job gem like https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq ?

Comment: you can send those photos in a bunch of 3 via ajax. This will reduce the time and will provide some feedback to the user as well.

Comment: Like @lacostenycoder said, use Sidekiq or Resque or another asynchronous job processor.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use delayed_job or whenever gem for background task, but I would like suggest [sidekiq](https://itnext.io/sidekiq-overview-and-how-to-deploy-it-to-heroku-b8811fea9347)

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem in a project. I came  accross a solution using AWS lambda. You can use carrierwave gem/ rails 5 active storage module if you are using rails to upload image on S3. If you are not using rails then use AWS-SDK for ruby to upload files on S3. You can bind events whenever a file created/modified on S3. Whenever a file created it will invoke lambda function and your work is done. can bind them to lambda function. In lambda function you can write logic to create files and upload it back to s3. You can write lambda code in ruby, node and python.

This strategy may help you.